# Sharing the EGL2.0 context between 2 GLSurfaceViews caused EGL_BAD_ACCESS on Android tablets

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0, glsurfaceview

I try to share EGL context bwteen 2 GLSurfaceViews by following code:

```
createContext(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display, EGLConfig eglConfig) {
    EGLContext shared = ...; // a cached egl context
    int[] attrib_list = { EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2, EGL10.EGL_NONE };
    EGLContext context = egl.eglCreateContext(display, eglConfig, shared == null ? EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT : shared,
        attrib_list);
    return context;
  }
}
```

The code **works on most of the android phones** (OS>=2.2) but failed on all the tested tablets.

> 01-12 18:33:35.381: E/AndroidRuntime(12171): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 11
>
> 01-12 18:33:35.381: E/AndroidRuntime(12171): java.lang.RuntimeException: eglMakeCurrent failed: EGL_BAD_ACCESS
>
> 01-12 18:33:35.381: E/AndroidRuntime(12171):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.throwEglException(GLSurfaceView.java:1146)

Since I declared the LOCAL_LDLIBS: = -lGLESv2, the EGL is a 2.0 context.

Why it failed on tablets(xoom, galaxy, lg, sony, etc)

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried a 'GLES20.glFlush();' before switching surfaces?

Answer (score 2):

Two possible reasons for this failure (from the EGL spec):

- If ctx is current to some other thread, or if either draw or read
  are bound to contexts in another thread, an EGL_BAD_ACCESS error is
  generated.
- If binding ctx would exceed the number of current
  contexts of that client API type supported by the implementation, an
  EGL_BAD_ACCESS error is generated.

It could also be that the GPU you are using on tablets does not support shared context.

Comment: I adjusted the timing for the context creating point and still got the same execption. And since I only test 2 contexts I guess the exception should be caused by the GPU. Have anybody done this sharing context thing succcessfully on any of Android tablets?

Comment: Any idea how many phones support only one context? Is there a manifest feature I can require for multiple context support?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably following lines are reason for the error in GLSurfaceView.

```
public GL createSurface(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    ....

    /*
     * Before we can issue GL commands, we need to make sure
     * the context is current and bound to a surface.
     */
    if (!mEgl.eglMakeCurrent(mEglDisplay, mEglSurface, mEglSurface, mEglContext)) {
         throwEglException("eglMakeCurrent");
    }

}
```